# I have a dataframe containing patient data. I want to obtain the sequence of procedures that each particular patient has undergone

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the Data Frame, the column titles are `Procedure Date`, `Patient ID` (`P1`,`P2` etc.) and `Procedure`.

I want to create a new DataFrame containing 4 columns, `Patient ID`, `Procedure 1`, ``` Procedure 2`` & ``` Procedure 3`, with the latter 3 containing each respective procedure, in order (from procedure date) of when they were performed, corresponding to each patient ID.

I then wish to create a 5th column, which contains the count of that particular order of procedures.

Essentially this is the desired output :

| Procedure 1 | Procedure 2 | Procedure 3 | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Angiogram | PCI |  | 6 |
| Angiogram | PCI | PCI | 3 |
| Angiogram | Angioplasty |  | 2 |

Comment: please provide sample data (in plain text), desired output of the sample data and explain what you have tried so far

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.